# How to stop a always running command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command that is constantly running. I used the new button "always active", but I don't know how to turn it off through another command block. Is there a way? Also, if there isn't, then is there a way to make a command block constantly run, but not with "always active"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/blockdata` to change a command block to <kbd>Needs Redstone</kbd>:

```
/blockdata X Y Z {auto:0b}
```

And to change it back to <kbd>Always Active</kbd>:

```
/blockdata X Y Z {auto:1b}
```

---

Alternatively, make the command block <kbd>Conditional</kbd>, which means that it will only run if the command block behind it was successful last time in ran:

[image: Conditional]

Here, the chain block will only run if whatever's in the repeat block was successful.

Comment: In 1.13, `/blockdata` was renamed to `/data merge block`, with the syntax otherwise unchanges